# Jest - manual mock user module

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I try to mock some module (verificationToken). So I create folder `__mock__` adjecent to my verificationToken module.

```
/actions
       | __mocks__
                   verificationToken.js
       | verificationToken.js
       | actions.js (import verificationToken from './verificationToken')
```

I created test for my component which uses actions.js. In action.js there is import statement. Jest clearly cannot mock verificationToken module and my test failed.

So then I tried to create folders `__mocks__` adjecent to `__tests__` folder but test also failed (same reason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found a solution.

*Note: In order to mock properly, Jest needs jest.mock('moduleName') to be in the same scope as the require/import statement.*

Create `__mock__` folder in actions.  In `component.test.js` give location to that folder which in my case is:

```
jest.mock('../../../actions/verificationToken');
```

Project folders:

```
actions
      |__mocks__
                 | verificationToken.js
      |actions.js
      |verificationToken.js

components
         | __tests__
                     |component.test.js
         | component.js
```